# xcodebuild process starts when using the man command in Macintosh Terminal

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal

When I first start a terminal session, and I use the man command, the result is delayed for a while. Yesterday, I noticed in the terminal bar that this xcodebuild was running. I do not remember seeing this in the past.

I deleted xcode and it no longer happened, but then I could not use clang or gcc in the terminal, so I reinstalled Xcode.

I still get the process as in the near past, but it does not take so long to get done.

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Thank you
trav

Comment: I think this might be answered at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/119864/xcodebuild-firing-after-every-terminal-command

Answer (score 0):

Update git by brew, it will fix.

https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/2189